# CURRENT_TIME format in esql

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

What is the default format of the function CURRENT_TIME in esql and how do we change it as per our requirements(24 hr or 12 hr formats)

Answer (score 6):

```
DECLARE castTime TIME;
SET castTime = CAST (timeValue AS TIME FORMAT timePattern)
```

where pattern can be

[image]

Comment: Please maek this as answer if this helped

Comment: Source: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ak05616_.htm?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify things a little more: The CURRENT_TIME function returns a value of the type TIME, which has no format. The format is only relevant when casting it to a CHARACTER:

```
DECLARE now12, now24 CHARACTER;
SET now12 = CAST (CURRENT_TIME AS CHARACTER FORMAT 'h:mma');
SET now24 = CAST (CURRENT_TIME AS CHARACTER FORMAT 'hh:mm');
```

To find the right format-string have a look at the other answers.

Comment: Ahh no 'h' means 12 hour suppress leading zeroes and 'hh' is 12 hour include leading zeroes. Its lower case 'h' 12 hour vs upper case 'H' 24 hour clocks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe whats missing is the information, how you can configure if you want to have 24h or 12h format. You can get this information from [the same source](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ak05616_.htm) @DaveZiegler mentioned:

- h  | hour in am or pm (1-12)
- hh | hour in am or pm (01-12)
- H  | hour of day in 24 hour form (0-23)
- HH | hour of day in 24 hour form (00-23)

There's a footnote for 24h format:

> 24-hour fields might result in an ambiguous time, if specified with a conflicting am/pm field.

So use `h`, `hh`, `H` or `HH` with the patterns listed in the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ak05616_.htm).